# how to add <script> tag into prestashop page in module file

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I use hookAuthentication of Prestashop, and I want to run a script in this Hook (Just onece when users log in):

> public function  hookAuthentication(){
>           }

and the script:

> var data ={ contact_id:5, title:'Mr',
>   gender:1, first_name:'Dupont', last_name:'Pierre'}

So how can I do?, please help me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

create a file mymodule.tpl inside the directory "views/templates/front/" at the end of function you can write:

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/mymodules.tpl');
```

inside mymodule.tpl enter:

```
{literal}
<script>
var data ={ contact_id:5, title:'Mr', gender:1, first_name:'Dupont', last_name:'Pierre'};
</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your script in a file, let's say `mymodule/js/myscript.js`, and then

```
public function hookAuthentication() {
  $this->context->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_ . 'mymodule/js/myscript.js');
}
```

This way you will load any script in the resulting page.